# R - Stacked Area chart

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-science

For the given data set how can i generate a stacked area chart Inflow vs. Date across different Sources in such a fashion that the maximum total inflow source is closest to the X (Date) axis and the least inflow source the farthest.

```
Date    Source  Inflow  
1/1/06  s1       271   
1/1/06  s3       368  
1/1/06  s2       425  
1/2/06  s4       580  
1/2/06  s2       233  
1/2/06  s3       243  
1/2/06  s1       428  
1/3/06  s5       164  
1/3/06  s2       461  
1/3/06  s3       180  
1/4/06  s1       258  
1/4/06  s2       153  
1/5/06  s6       443
```

`ggplot(data, aes(x=Inflow, y=Date, fill=Source)) +
  geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens", breaks=rev(levels(data$Source)))`

[image: Please find the attached Plot]

Comment: If you want a better piece of code, it would be helpful if you tell us what is wrong with it according to you .....

Comment: Also: don't give your object the same name as a function, see `?data`.

Comment: I think my code is wrong. Not getting a stacked chart at all.

Comment: Now you made your question even worse by removing the code you used. Please include it again (and also the resulting plot).

Comment: i have added the code and the plot aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, stacked area chart does not make much sense with the data you provide, as some categories are found on a single day (so there is nowhere for the area to expand, hence the vertical lines).

Stacked bar chart may be the way to go.

```
library("tidyverse")


records <- tribble(~Date, ~Source, ~Inflow, 
        "1/1/06",  "s1",      271,   
        "1/1/06",  "s3",      368,  
        "1/1/06",  "s2",      425,  
        "1/2/06",  "s4",      580,  
        "1/2/06",  "s2",      233,  
        "1/2/06",  "s3",      243,  
        "1/2/06",  "s1",      428,  
        "1/3/06",  "s5",      164,  
        "1/3/06",  "s2",      461,  
        "1/3/06",  "s3",      180,  
        "1/4/06",  "s1",      258,  
        "1/4/06",  "s2",      153,  
        "1/5/06",  "s6",      443)

records %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(lubridate::mdy(Date))) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Date, y=Inflow, fill=Source)) +
  geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4, position = position_stack()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens")
```

[image]

```
records %>%  
  mutate(Date = as.Date(lubridate::mdy(Date))) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Date, y=Inflow, fill=Source)) +
  geom_col(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4, position = position_stack()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks giocomai. I would also want to arrange in such as fashion that the maximum total inflow source is closest to the X (Date) axis and the least inflow source the farthest.

Comment: by "maximum total inflow source" you mean, maximum total inflow on each separate day, or which source on average is highest, and locate it accordingly every dat? Given your original question on geom_area, now I believe that may what you were looking for is actually part of the `ggalluvial` package, which orders areas as you suggest. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html - check out the example graph titled "refugee volume by country and region of origin"